# How to have hasOne relation with embedded always relation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

EmberJS has removed hasOne in the earlier revision. Whats the way to create such a nested object relation where I want to have hasOne

Removal of hasOne has been done in favor of belongsTo, can anyone share a thought on how to write {embedded : always} relation between nested JSON.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I know that this question is old and answered, but since it is one of the top
>   search results for "ember hasone" i wanted to share my findings on the subject. 
>   I've read the link in the first answer but the example is kinda outdated.

The "embedded" flag is obsolete, "DS.RESTAdapter.map" is not a function and the "DS.hasOne" method deprecated.

The current 1.0.0-beta.2 solution for emulating the "hasOne relationship" is simply using "DS.belongsTo". They are not very different and you just need to add the hasOne foreignKeys to your result-set just like you would with belongsTo.

**Source:** https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/a466741a36731c5d382df33461268024627325ef

Here's an example server response from a complex model.

```
{"users": [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "profile": 27,        // merged hasone
  "image": 3,           // merged hasone
  "account_id": 64      // an actual belongsTo
}]}
```

And then as model

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   profile: DS.belongsTo('profile'),
   image: DS.belongsTo('image'),
   account_id: DS.belongsTo('account')
});
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for info on how to model a hasOne

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the mapping on the adapter, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521612/793002) for a working example.