# Ember data embedded has one relationship for ember-data.1.0.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to serialize a user object and pass it to an ember client. My app uses the RESTserializer.

A user object has_one address object. There is no separate endpoint for just the address so I can't just provide a foreign key id and sideload it.

The JSON received just includes address as an object and looks something like this:

```
{"user": 
   {
    "id":"5",
    "name":"Andrew",
    "address": 
      { 
        "id":"3",
         "addressable_id":"5",
         "street":"1",
         "country_code":"US"
      }
   }
```

On the ember side I have a user model

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),

  address: DS.belongsTo('address'),

  //hasOne via belongsTo as suggested by another SO post:
  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686253/how-to-have-hasone-relation-with-embedded-always-relation
});
```

and an address model

```
App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
  addressable_id: DS.attr('string'),
  street: DS.attr('string'),
  country_code: DS.attr('string'),

  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

Currently running this code throw an error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined
```

which can be fixed by removing the

```
address: DS.belongsTo('address'),
```

line in the user model but then the relationship doesn't load properly.

So what am I doing wrong configuring this? I am having a hell of a time finding up to date documentation on this.

Comment: Are you using the [embedded record mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222457/ember-data-embedded-records-current-state/24224682#24224682)?

Comment: Actually looks like I may have misinterpreted the link you sent. That may fix my issue.

Comment: That worked! If you resubmit that as an answer with some context I will accept it. Thank you so much! I had been wrestling with that for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) on a per-type serializer.

In your case, you would need to do the following :

```
App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    address: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

as explained in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222457/ember-data-embedded-records-current-state/24224682#24224682).