# Ember Data, how to use registerTransform

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been Googling for a while now, but haven't found any good solution.

The root of the problem is that my records aren't being set to `isDirty` when using this method:

```
DS.JSONTransforms.object = {
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return Ember.isNone(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return Ember.isNone(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
  }
}
```

From what I gather this is an old method that apparently still works, since it handles the JSON objects I'm throwing at it, but it's not setting my records to `isDirty` when making edits.

What you now should be using is `registerTransform` on your adapter (according to this https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/517). But my custom transform isn't being registered, so I guess I'm putting it at the wrong place (same place as my previous JSONTransforms).

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('object', {
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return Em.none(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return Em.none(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
  }
});
```

Any one have knowledge to share about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with `isDirty` is not because you're not using `registerTransform`, the behavior will be the same.

For now, Ember Data does not support object attributes, one of the difficulty is in fact to observe the changes to set the `isDirty` flag.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/53) for this that you can track on github.

A workaround would be to declare the nested objects as proper `DS.Model` and set an embedded relationship between them.

For the example, let's say you have a date object sended with a post :

```
{post: {
  id: 12
  title: "EmberData accept object attributes, you do not need this anymore !!"
  date: {
    day: "01"
    month: "03"
    year: "2013"
  }
}}
```

You will declare the model as following :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.belongsTo('App.PostDate')
});

App.PostDate = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post'),
  day: DS.attr('string'),
  month: DS.attr('string'),
  year: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

And add a mapping in your adapter :

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Post',{
  date:{
    embedded:'always'
  }
})
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521612/793002) for more detail about the embedded mapping option.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem I'm facing is that my JSON returns an Object with unknown attributes. So I guess it's not really possible to define a Model for me in this case. But now I know how to design around this issue at least, thanks again.

Comment: How to tackle deep cases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896049/emberjs-multi-level-hierarchy-with-embedded-always

Answer (score 0):

I disagree.  I think its inefficient and overly complex to have to have extra calls for all your child relationships/records.  I found a work around for this.  Add a field for 'last_updated' and after you change the value of your nested stuff, just update the last_updated to the current time, that will trigger the 'isDirty' flag and allow you to update...