# Ember-data model according recieved JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, jsonp, ember-data

I get JSON with structure like this:

```
{
  "description":"text",
  "images":[{"id":"1","url":"image url"},{"id":"2","url":"url"}],
  "seats":3,
  "taken_seats":[{"number":1,"id":"1"},{"number":3,"id":"2"}],
  "title":"vel ad eius",
  "id":"1",
  "options":[]
}
```

How to structurize DS.model to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String values** (description, title) will use a `DS.attr('string')`

**Number** (seats) will use a `DS.attr('number')`

**Arrays** (images, taken_seats, options) will use a relation like `DS.hasMany('App.Image')`, you will have to set the mapping in the adapter to `embedded` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521612/793002) for details.

You may feel like you do not need a relationship for arrays, like for example if you do not want / can list the possible keys of object in the options array. The solution would be to register a custom transform for your needs then you may encounter some unexcepted behavior, particularly with the `isDirty` flag of the object, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697200/793002) for details