# EmberData - DIsplay belongsTo relationship in Handlebars Template

Tags: ember.js, associations, ember-data

I've got a handlebars template that is displaying a list of articles. Each article has two prompts associated with it through a belongsTo relationship. The information is correctly coming back from the server with this JSON:

```
{"article":[{"id":7,"prompt_one":{"content":"Thing1"},"prompt_two":{"content":"Thing2"}]}
```

Now I'm able to render the other data from the article okay, however I haven't been able to get the data from one of the prompts to render in the handlebars template. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
<p>{{prompt_one.content}}</p>
```

But nothing shows up and no errors are displayed. What's the proper way to render associated models content?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Embedded records. If the prompt objects are embedded into the article's JSON you will need to define them as embedded ([ember-data does not support embedded objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521182/ember-data-does-not-support-embedded-objects)).

   ```
   DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Article',{
       prompt:{
           embedded:'always'
       }
   })

   App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
       prompt: DS.belongsTo(App.Prompt,{embedded:'always'}),
   });
   ```
2. Custom object attribute. If you just want to embed objects and not use a `belongsTo` relationship you can register your own `DS.attr('object')` type.

   ```
   DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('object', {
     deserialize: function(serialized) {
       return Ember.isEmpty(serialized) ? {} : JSON.parse(serialized);
     },
     serialize: function(deserialized) {
       return Ember.isEmpty(deserialized) ? '' : JSON.stringify(deserialized);
     }
   });
   ```