# How to access nested object in json with Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember data and having a hard time figuring out get ember to recognize nested properties in my JSON response from the server.  This is ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js.

Currently, I've set up associated models with Ember data revision 11.  Here the

```
# School Model
App.School = DS.Model.extend
  addr:       DS.belongsTo('App.Addr')

  name:       DS.attr 'string'
  status:     DS.attr 'string'

# Address Model
App.Addr = DS.Model.extend
  school:   DS.belongsTo 'App.School'

  line1:    DS.attr 'string'
  city:     DS.attr 'string'
  state:    DS.attr 'string'
  iso:      DS.attr 'string'
```

And here is the JSON response from my server:

```
{"schools":
 [{
    "_id":"51020261bbc3b8c526000007",
    "name":"Willamette",
    "status":"p",
    "addr":{
      "line1":"122 Evergreen Terrace",
      "city":"Springfield",
      "state":"IL",
      "iso":"US"
    }
   }    
  ]}
```

My adapter is set up as follows:

```
    App.Store = DS.Store.extend
      revision: 11
      adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api"
        serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend
        primaryKey: (type) ->
          '_id';
      })
```

UPDATE: 
I've tried to map the addr property, as follows. Still no dice...

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map 'App.School', 
  addr: { embedded: 'always'}
```

In my template, I'd like to do something like this...

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="school">
      <h2>School: {{name}}</h2>
      <p> Status: {{ status }}</p>
      <p> Address: {{ addr.line1 }} {{ addr.city }} </p>
    </script>
```

The name and status properties render fine.  But addr.line1 and addr.city are blank.  Is there a way to get Ember to recognize the nested addr propeties?

Thanks!

Comment: match post as answered

Answer (score 6):

Since you're embedding the addr JSON in your schools JSON you need to setup the mapping in the DS.RESTAdapter.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map 'App.School',
  addr: { embedded: 'always' }
```

The embedded option can have two values, 1) always, 2) load.

See Yehuda's answer here for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324532/1409279

Comment: Thanks!  I added the line from your answer but it still doesn't seem to load the embedded addr object.  Maybe I'm defining the models incorrectly?  Sorry, I'm a complete Ember noob :/

Comment: Got it working with a tiny change.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6):

Did you get time to look at

[Ember Data: Model Fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments)

It allows nested data

Answer (score 2):

Looks like sma's answer was correct, I just needed a reference to the adapter first.  This bit...

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map 'App.School', addr {embedded: 'always' }
```

...gives an error 'cannot call map of undefined'.  So updated to...

```
    App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
      bulkCommit: false


    App.Adapter.map 'App.School', {
      addr: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
```

Works now!

Comment: Can you try the same with two level deep nesting ?