# Modelling a nested json structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following `json` data:

```
{
    "type": "type1",
    "name": "Name1",
    "properties": {
        "age": 23,
        "address": "Sample"
    }
}
```

I am modelling this with `Ember Data`, as follows:

```
App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    properties: DS.belongsTo('App.NodeProperties')
});

App.NodeProperties = DS.Model.extend({
    age: DS.attr('number'),
    address: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Is there a better way to model the nested `properties` than using a `DS.belongsTo`?
How would I access the age in my templates. I am currently doing

```
{{node.properties.age}}
```

But I am not sure this is working.

Comment: If you have a well defined properties model belongsTo is the way to go.

Comment: So then `{{node.properties.age}}` would be the right way to access this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to model the nested properties than using a DS.belongsTo?

DS.belongsTo is a good choice given your use case.

> How would I access the age in my templates?

`{{node.properties.age}}` is right, assuming that `{{node}}` is a valid reference

> But I am not sure this is working.

There are a few more steps you'll need to take to get this working. First, add a mapping for App.Node to the rest adapter specifying that properties will be embedded:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Node', {
  properties: { embedded: 'always' }
};
```

Then update NodeProperties to include the relationship:

```
App.NodeProperties = DS.Model.extend({
  age: DS.attr('number'),
  address: DS.attr('string'),
  node: DS.belongsTo('App.Node')
});
```

For more info, check out these answers:

- [Ember Data Embedded Loading Integration Test](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_loading_test.js)
- [How to access nested object in json with Ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591892/how-to-access-nested-object-in-json-with-ember-data)
- [How to make embedded hasMany relationships work with ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320925/how-to-make-embedded-hasmany-relationships-work-with-ember-data/14324532#14324532)