# How to display nested data in template from Ember.js model using basic adapter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.BasicAdapter.create()
});
```

Model:

```
var Profiles = DS.Model.extend({
    displayName: DS.attr('string'),
    profileName: DS.attr('string')
}),
User = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    phone: DS.attr('string'),
    profiles: DS.hasMany(Profiles, {embedded: true})
});
```

JSON data for model:

```
{
    "email": "some email",
    "phone": "some phone number",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "displayName": "some name",
            "profileName": "some name"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "some name",
            "profileName": "some name"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the template:

```
{{#if model.isLoaded}}
    email: {{model.email}} // displayed
    {{model.profiles.length}} // number of objects in array is displayed

    {{#each model.profiles}}
        // this line generates error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
           '_create' of undefined ember-data.js:2560
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Any idea why this line generates an error? Especially if `model.profiles.length` displays correct value?

Answer (score 0):

At first, the syntax you used for embedding `Profiles` in user is not relevant anymore. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324532/793002) for a proper way to set this.

Comment: Does it mean I can't use local variable `Profiles` and I have to use it in application namespace like `App.Profiles`?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, maybe you can use `Profiles` in the mapping directly.