# Get object from belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have some model like:

```
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),

  department: DS.belongsTo('App.Department')    
});
```

In my controller I can say

```
var name = thisEmployee.get('name');
```

But I can't say

```
var department = thisEmployee.get('department');
```

So my question is how to get a reference to the object on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: why you can't say `thisEmployee.get('department');` in your controller, what happens? do you get an error? or it returns null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the problem lies in the fact that you maybe don't have specified how your relationships should load... try setting up your adapter map like this:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Employee', {
  department: {embedded: 'always'}
});
```

This should side load your `department` relationships automatically on requesting the parent model `Employee` with e.g. `App.Employee.find();`.

Hope it helps

Comment: That was it :)  One thing to note: it didn't work until I moved the code to be before the App.Store block, where the adapter is created.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @kmiyashiro, nowhere. You find this out rather in two ways 1. reading the source code, or 2.see this answer from Yehuda Katz (ember core team) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320925/how-to-make-embedded-hasmany-relationships-work-with-ember-data