# How to embed n layers of JSON payload?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324532/1406664) describing how to tell Ember Data's adapter that the JSON payload is coming in embedded:

```
// data.json
{ 
  company: {
    id: "Acme Inc.",
    contracts: [
      {
        date: 2013-02-03,
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}

// models.js
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
  contracts: DS.hasMany('App.Contract')
});

App.Contract = DS.Model.extend({
  company: DS.belongsTo('App.Company'),
  ...
});

DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Company', {
    contracts: { embedded: 'always' }
};
```

My question is, how can I do this for multiple levels of nesting?

```
// data.json
{ 
  company: {
    id: "Acme Inc.",
    contracts: [
      {
        date: 2013-02-03,
        ...
        schedules: [
          { 
            amount: 1,402,
            ...
          },
          ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried adding

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Contract', {
  schedules: { embedded: 'always' }
};
```

but it didn't work.