# Does ember.js still support embedded relationships?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

My Setup

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I understand ember-data by default wants "sideloaded relationships".

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships

It simply doesn't make any sense to me why they would choose to design their REST adapter as such. Regardless I've seen some posts that suggest I can embed the relationships:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324532/1251349
- http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-embedded-records-handling/4132

However can't seem to get it to work. The answer's I've found are of older versions of emberjs. So I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or the old solutions no longer work.

**TL:DR;** Does ember-data still support "embedded relationships"

Here is an example of what I got:

```
GDL.Event = DS.Model.extend(
  title: DS.attr('string')
  time: DS.attr('date')
  time_i: DS.attr('number')
  live: DS.attr('boolean')
  category: { embedded: 'load' }
)

GDL.Category = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr('string')
)
```

My JSON

```
{
  "events":[
    {
      "id":2411,
      "title":"Green Bay Packers vs. Seattle Seahawks",
      "time":"2014-09-05T00:30:00.000Z",
      "time_i":1409877000,
      "category":{
        "id":109,
        "name":"Football"
      }
    },
    {
      "id":2412,
      "title":"New Orleans Saints vs. Atlanta Falcons",
      "time":"2014-09-07T17:00:00.000Z",
      "time_i":1410109200,
      "category":{
        "id":109,
        "name":"Football"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Reading your discuss question you seem to describe some other problems you may be experiencing, if this doesn't answer your question lemme know and I'll reopen.

Comment: Here's an example with your code (it looks like you don't have the relationship type defined for category, `category: { embedded: 'load' }`): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/874/edit

Comment: I love you. I was about to just give up. All I needed extra was to define `App.CategorySerializer` (along with `GDL.EventSerializer`)

Comment: BTW: I just tried `category: { embedded: 'load' }` and it doesn't seem to work. However `category: { embedded: 'always' }` does. Have any ideas why?

Comment: I don't think `embedded: 'load'` is a supported option, it looks like only `always` works with Ember Data currently, https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/embedded_records_mixin.js#L422