# Ember data RestAdapter embedded hasMany

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, ember-data

How do i make this work with ember-data?

```
{"poll":{"id":1,"question":"lym features",
    "choices":[{"id":1,"text":"Improve AI", "PollId":1},
               {"id":2,"text":"Multiplayer","PollId":1},
               {"id":3,"text":"Modern Art","PollId":1}]}}
```

That's my json response from the server. I need ember data RESTAdapter to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EmberData EmbeddedRecordsMixin http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html and set `choices` to be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

I have to override `extractSingle` method in `DS.RESTSerializer`. See the emberjs link in the code for details.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320925/how-to-make-embedded-hasmany-relationships-work-with-ember-data
// http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractSingle
App.PollSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
        var poll = payload.poll;
        var choices = poll.choices;
        delete poll.choices;

        poll.choices = [];

        choices.forEach(function(c) {
            poll.choices.push(c.id);
        });

        payload = { choices: choices, poll: payload.poll };
        return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
    }
});
```

This turns my original structure into standard form.

Note: Ignorant fool that downvoted, is there a simpler way to do this, am i in some kind of pitfall, explain yourself.